# Out of stock uses normal price woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to set things up so that woocommerce will change a sale product back to the original price when the stock runs out.

I've written this snippet:

```
if ($product->get_stock_quantity()<1){

$price = $product->regular_price;

}
```

The problem is I'm not sure where to put it and if it's entirely correct. I can't see price.php in woocommerce > single product.

Comment: https://sceptermarketing.com/how-to-change-the-woocommerce-price-via-functions-php/ this is reference link for hook

Answer (score 1):

Use this code in function.php

```
function return_custom_price($price, $product) {
   if ($product->get_stock_quantity()<1){
       $price = $product->regular_price;
   }
   return $price;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price', 'return_custom_price', 10, 2);
```